# Срабатывание события после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который генерирует и выводит список select с уже выделенным option на странице при загрузке страницы, как сделать чтоб после загрузки страницы сработала функция с отправкой (ajax) значения выделенного option

Answer (score 1):

Если в select установлен обработчик события `change` то нужно при инициализации страницы его вызвать методом `trigger`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#my-select').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my-select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){

 $('select option:selected').change(function function_name(argument) {
  $.ajax({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '',
   data: $.param($(this))
  })
 }).change()

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="">
   <option value="некоторые parametrs 1">некоторые parametrs 1</option>
   <option value="некоторые parametrs 2">некоторые parametrs 2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```